# inactive form after visted once in windows phone javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-8.1

i've developed and app in windows platform for windows phone 8.1(javascript), now am face a bug which is creating a big issue, the template i used in developing the app was navigation app, so i used page control to navigate easily, the bug i have is once i enter a page which contains form, and doing all stuffs.... its ok, but the thing is when i navigate back to previous page and enter again the FORM GOES INACTIVE, anything request is not responding, but when i close that app and reopen it, it works, please help me on this issue. awaiting for helpfull answers. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using CacheMode.Required or something that keeps your page loaded - in this case method OnNavigatedTo will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

I was using all the JavaScript in the same html, but in Windows it all has to be given in ready function(page control) even if it is a jQuery code.